# How to set in meteor --mobile-server when using nginx

Tags: ios, meteor, nginx

I have on digitalocean my meteor application running but when I try and test on my iphone the app I am not able to see the login screen.

I don't think it's version dependent and I therefore do not list them. I am happy to provide all the config files if this helps but want to make sure that I am not missing anything conceptually.

My setup is that on my digitalocean (not real URL: https://ABC123.com) server I run the meteor app and the app works fine at the URL. The meteor application has been deployed a while back and is a different release from what I am testing now locally. Source code is quite similar though and it never worked on the iphone. nginx is used to forward the URL domain to

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3100;
```

Here is the issue now:
I run from my local mac:

```
meteor run ios-device --mobile-server https://ABC123.com
```

and run from xcode on the simulator or my iphone and get the attached screenshot. You can see that there is no login prompt which I believe is caused that I do not connect to the server on digitalocean.

[image: iPhone with missing login prompt]

It's a also surprising that with the command meteor runs on localhost:3000 as well. But it's probably not the issue.

The way it should look is the below which is taken from the web page:

[image: web page with login prompt]

Thanks already in advance for any responses.

Comment: When you built this code and put in on the server, did you add `platform ios`? If you connect to your simulator for debugging (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html) and call `Meteor.status();` what does it say?

Comment: @TIC. Hmm, I get: {status: "waiting", connected: false, retryCount: 7, retryTime: 1476727587713.171} = $1

Comment: @TIC safari console also shows: [Error] Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname could not be found. (info, line 0) but it's not stating which server it's looking for.

Comment: Look in the Network tab and see what URL it is using

Comment: So, the issue is caused by SSL. I see in Safari: Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “ABC123.com” which could put your confidential information at risk. Next step will be to fix my SSL but would like to avoid incurring cost. Do you know if SSL certificates can be free or if I can remove  the need for SSL with meteor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved. Using Safari as a debugger I noticed that the connection to the server failed due to a non AC SSL certificate. So, after I fixed the SSL certificates it does connect now.